# Sangría en XCode

Tags: xcode

Buenas!

¿Alguien sabe desde dónde se puede modificar la sangría en el código en Xcode?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!!

Comment: ¿Has mirado las preferencias en `XCode > Preferences > Text Editing > Indentation`? ¿Cuál es el problema que tienes exactamente? Deberías hacer tu pregunta más descriptiva para que sea más fácil ayudarte y pueda servir para otros usuarios en el futuro. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `preferencias->edición de texto->editar (Indentation)` yo lo tengo en inglés pero te servirá igual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]